# Is it a good practice to have field data turned to true in production deployments of Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I was developing my code locally with elasticsearch and field data was turned off so I used `.keyword` with my text fields as a workaround for this. But when I deployed my code on gcp I found out that my endpoints were failing, I removed the `.keyword` from my field names and the code started working

I realised that maybe my org had set field data = true in the deployment, I have been wondering then is this a good practice. Wouldn't it hog up memory?

What do other devs do? do they use field data = true or use `.keyword` as a workaround instead in production and staging environments.

Comment: May you show the mappings you use locally and have in production? Should be the output of `GET index/_mapping`.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all recommended to use field data in production.
A complete answer is given [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/support-in-the-wild-my-biggest-elasticsearch-problem-at-scale)